# Validate user login MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, controller, return

I have a webapp, when I logged in, it redirect me to home/Index, so if I press back on my explorer it redirects me to login again, but I want that user cannot entry if a user is logged...:

In my Regiester controller I use USerName field:

```
  var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName};
```

So, in my login controller I try somthing like this:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
if (UserName == Login())
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index"/"Home");
        }}
```

but first, it no catch my UserName variable.. how can I do it? or there are any other method like loggout if user click back to Account/register(principal) in my case.